# How to close all open dialogs of a given SWT shell?

Tags: java, swt

My program opens a dialog (on a given shell):

```
new FileDialog(shell).open();
```

My Question is: How can I (in another part of my program) close all open dialogs of a given
shell?

```
private void closeDialogs(Shell shell) {
    // how to close open dialogs?
}
```

Below is minimal test case, one button opens the dialogs. The other button should
close all open dialogs of the current shell.

[image]

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final Display display = new Display();

    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setText("Testcase");
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    final Button button = new Button(shell, SWT.PUSH);
    button.setText("Open Dialog");
    button.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(final SelectionEvent e) {
            new NonModalDialog(shell).open();
        }
    });

    Button button2 = new Button(shell, SWT.PUSH);
    button2.setText("Close open dialogs");
    button2.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            // How to close all open dialogs of the given shell?
        }
    });

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
            display.sleep();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to collect the dialogs in a list as you open them.

When the "close" button is clicked, walk through the list and close the dialogs.

Note: This will not work when any of the dialogs are modal. A modal dialog will take over the event loop and ignore any events that aren't directed at itself, so clicking on the button will be impossible.

Comment: Thanks, the non working close button is no problem, I do not have a button and put it there only for asking (a simpler) question.
Are you sure that I have to manually remember the dialogs?

Comment: I'm not sure but I don't know any other way. You can iterate over all the shells as Baz suggested but there is no simple way to determine whether a `Shell` is currently displaying a dialog or a normal window. What you can do is look into the sources for Dialog, you'll see that they aren't added to any kind of list where you could look them up. So you'll have to do it yourself.